# Stored Procedure not working with variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[GetDrugPackID]
    @Search as nvarchar
As
Begin
    SELECT DrgPack.ID, DrgPack.PackSize, Drg.BrandName, Drg.DIN, Drg.Strength
  FROM [Pharmacy].[dbo].[DrgPack] INNER JOIN
  Drg ON Drg.ID = DrgPack.DrgID INNER JOIN
  DrgPackUPc ON DrgPack.ID = DrgPackUpc.DrgPackId
  WHERE DrgPackUpc.Upc = '@Search'
End
```

When I run the above by passing the search variable as 04029125070527 I get no results.

But if I edit my stored procedure as follows, I get a result. The only difference is in the above I'm trying to send the variable and in the second its hard coded (not what I want to do, just trying to debug).

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[GetDrugPackID]
    @Search as nvarchar
As
Begin
    SELECT DrgPack.ID, DrgPack.PackSize, Drg.BrandName, Drg.DIN, Drg.Strength
  FROM [Pharmacy].[dbo].[DrgPack] INNER JOIN
  Drg ON Drg.ID = DrgPack.DrgID INNER JOIN
  DrgPackUPc ON DrgPack.ID = DrgPackUpc.DrgPackId
  WHERE DrgPackUpc.Upc = '04029125070527'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you forgot to set the length of your var "@Search as nvarchar" it needs to be "@Search as nvarchar(50)" or what ever length you need

Comment: The datatype of `@Search` should match exactly what `DrgPackUpc.Upc` is. So if that is `varchar(20)` for example then you should use that rather than `nvarchar(50)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the size of your `nvarchar` parameter.  Without a size declaration, your parameter is declared implicitly as an `nvarchar(1)`.

In addition, your parameter should not be in single quotes.

```
WHERE DrgPackUpc.Upc = @Search
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was it, I missed both of those

Comment: Please mark as an answer if it solved your question.

Comment: Will do, I'm required to wait 10 minutes to select as solved.